# Quote not setting on payment session after a while

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have a problem in creating a  order programatically.
It was working fine, but since a couple of days it stopped on the error:

'Fatal error: Call to a member function getStore() on a non-object in /home/clubecaf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php on line 165 '

It locates at:

```
    public function getMethodInstance()
{
    $method = parent::getMethodInstance();
    return $method->setStore($this->getQuote()->getStore());
}
```

Located in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment.

**Is there a reason why magento stops to correctly treat the quote session into quote_payment, after a time where payment quote tables have a certain size or state?**

*Debugging process and background :*

The error clearly indicates that my quote instance is not correctly set.

But , debugging, i saw that after quote save his own instance on magneto, on method aftersave of quote  he calls a function called this->getPaymentsCollection()->save() , where sales_flat_quote_payment set its quote to database and payment session.

On database, the field quote_id of sales_flat_quote_payment is filled.

After this , i made a secured local copy of the store, and erased the sales_flat_quote_payment content, correcting the errors.

But since i cannot erase old payment quotes, i have to be more precise on the definition of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: 
I made a test, erasing half of the registers of sales_flat_quote_payment . And it work out either.
So, i suppose that the problem is the size of the table.

Comment: Update: if i delete half part that has the lowest payment_id it does't work. But when i do it with the higher part, it works.